# @font-face not working at all

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I dont understand whats going on here because when I had this code on its own it was working (in FireFox):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mmfont';
    src: url('/scripts/mmfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I added a second font in exactly the same manner, but only the first one was working:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mmfont2';
    src: url('/scripts/mmfont2.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I used a font-generator to get an EOT file for IE9 and generate the @font-face code for me, but now neither font is working in any browser (I tried IE9, FF12, Chrome & Safari5).

I then put the @font-face CSS in its own '/scripts/fonts.css' file so that the fonts and CSS were in the same folder, and I tried to use the URLs both directly ('mmfont.ttf') and by the webroot folder ('/scripts/mmfont.ttf') but still neither way is working at all.

What am I doing wrong?

## Correction:

I had a typo when calling the first font 'mmfont' I did this: `font-family: mm_font` but now that I fixed the typo, once again only the 1st font is working with the code below, and the second font `mmfont2` is not working. I tried to re-arrange the order (define the 2nd font first) but it still wont work. So now I believe there is a problem with my font file, so I will try to get another copy and see how that goes.

## Update:

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code. I used FireBug to do a Source Edit of the fonts.css file, and when I renamed the url for 'mmfont2' to 'mmfont.ttf' (the URL for the 1st font) it updated the page and the font loaded, however when I renamed it back to 'mmfont2.ttf' it went back to the default font of the browser. So I am now sure it is a problem with the font file rather than the code.

It looks like this 2nd font I'm using isn't a web-compatible font. Funnily, it turns out that all along the same font has another alias "Century Gothic" which is a web-safe font and works in all the browsers without even having to link any files!!

(I don't know if I should have this question closed or deleted)

---

## /scripts/fonts.css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mmfont';
    src: url('/scripts/mmfont.eot');
    src: url('/scripts/mmfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/scripts/mmfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mmfont2';
    src: url('/scripts/mmfont2.eot');
    src: url('/scripts/mmfont2.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/scripts/mmfont2.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

## /index.html

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="/scripts/fonts.css" type="text/css">
```

---

## directory

```
/  
/index.html  
/scripts/  
/scripts/mmfont.ttf  
/scripts/mmfont.eot  
/scripts/mmfont2.ttf  
/scripts/mmfont2.eot
/scripts/fonts.css
```

Comment: Can you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo for us to see this in action? Obviously you'll have to link to your font-files, though. So there may be a (potential) licensing issue.

Comment: Not the solution probably, but add `type=text/css` in the `<link>` tag.

Comment: Also, remove the `/scripts` directory indications from the css file *that is already in that /scripts folder*.

Comment: @poepje oops, I added that but yeah, its not the solution. And yes I did remove the `/scripts/` part of the URL as I mentioned in my post too

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm currently working on localhost so I wouldn't be able to upload the font, and it is a font which has a license on it so I can't upload it

Comment: @Ozzy did you ever figure this out?  I'm having a similar issue, but it appears to be limited to Firefox only, although all I need to do is add white-space while doing a source edit to get the correct font to appear.

Comment: @PaulPettengill I couldn't work it out, so in the end I stuck to one font definition and I took out the folder name in the SRC, because the CSS and TTF files were in the same folder. I also went back to basics...only defining the TTF :/

Comment: @Ozzy Thanks! I ended up just embedding the font definitions in my css file.  Ended up being the only way I could make it work.

Comment: @PaulPettengill embedding the font definitions in your css file? Sorry I didn't understand. Why don't you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We couldn't figure out another way around, as it appeared all of our settings on Amazon were fine.  Instead, we just embedded the font definition itself into a data-uri call, as seen below.  Much of the font definition has been omitted to size constraints of answers in StackOverflow, but this should give you a good idea of our approach.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "PFDinTextPro-Light";
    src: url("233cd7_2_0-webfont.eot");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "PFDinTextPro-Light";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("233cd7_2_0-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAFq4ABEAAAAAmrQAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABGRlRNAAABgAAAABwAAAAcYqvy...dRcDMyMXA5M2mM+m4LqJvRPKYQVy2CKhHBYgh9USyuGAaJOCaeMESnLMgHAYN3BBDecFinIdZ9LeyOxWBuTyALm8+XAuN5DLEwjn8oGM5Kr/zwAX4Qcq4HsC5woAufy1MG7kBhFtANGLRQMAAVB7j+oAAA==") format("woff"), url("233cd7_2_0-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: Your post was flagged by the system for excessively long content - I think saying to embed the font using a data URI will suffice.

Comment: @BoltClock I've removed most of the data from the URI, let me know if the post is still showing up as excessively long.

Comment: Not anymore - we dismissed the flag on the assumption you'd edit the answer yourself :) For the sake of completeness you'll want to explain what is happening here in plain English, to help other readers see at a glance what your answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

Hey now correct to your font url in css as like this

```
url('mmfont.eot');
```

i think your font and css file in one folder of **scripts**

Comment: @hcharge if your read my post fully, I tried that already, but still it wont load the font

Comment: Hi now http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator uplod .ttf font and ganrate to css kit all browser and used to this

Comment: @RohitAzad I used font-squirrel to get that code already... its from font-squirrel

Comment: can u show me live path of your page than you apply this font

Comment: @RohitAzad I'm working offline on localhost... but I put all the relevant code in my post. The font is there because when I go to localhost:3333/scripts/mmfont.ttf it asks me to download the font

Comment: now used to this url('../scripts/mmfont2.ttf') if your css if outer in css folder and fonts is scripts folder ..........

Comment: @RohitAzad No dude, they're all in the `scripts` folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13456/discussion-between-rohit-azad-and-ozzy)

Answer (score 1):

Know it's over a year later but just incase anyone comes looking, I'm betting the questioner was hosting their website on AWS -- you have to create a CORS rule to get AWS to read @font-face kit. Try this fix as described here: http://blog.blenderbox.com/2012/10/12/serving-font-face-fonts-to-firefox-from-an-s3-bucket/