# Recognizing custom icon fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

The issue is that my website doesn't recognize the custom icon fonts that I feed it through css.

**Here is the problem in detail:**
Basically, I've followed the tutorial from over here: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ResponsiveIconGrid/ and I successfully implemented it on my website. The functionality, the styles - everything is in check. Except that in place of the icons, I see rectangles/squares. I have already tried this with two other icon fonts.

**My CSS and HTML**
For detailed/full CSS codes, please visit pastebin over here: http://pastebin.com/94UgpN8B and over here http://pastebin.com/c7w1LEBf

**My code in short**
Adding the fonts with @font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'anyoldicon';
    src:url('assets/anyoldicon.eot');
    src:url('assets/anyoldicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('assets/anyoldicon.woff') format('woff'),
       url('assets/anyoldicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('assets/anyoldicon.svg#anyoldicon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    unicode-range: U+00-FFFF;
}
```

And calling the via `<span>` in HTML. Please refer to the above full files to check out the CSS that takes care of inheriting. It seems to work fine to me.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="cbp-ig-icon cbp-ig-icon-whippy"></span>
        <h3 class="cbp-ig-title">George</h3>
        <span class="cbp-ig-category">Smith</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

- I haven't received any 404 errors in console regarding the assets.
- I also tried defining the icons styles separately, so as to remove the possibility of incorrect inheriting of class properties (check out the pastebin CSS)
- I have tried adding my font-family like so:     font-family: 'anyoldicon', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;?
- My folder structure is basically that in the root of the website directory there is a folder called assets and in that folder are all my css files and font files. Not very clean, I know, but I am still testing the website. There are other folders like css and images, but there reside mostly Muse files, which have no relation to the specific issue. Also my html files are in the root as well.
- I have tried changing the paths to different folders, and putting ../ infront of them. The manner of linking to the fonts is the same way I link to my other documents, which seems to work fine.
- Cleared cache inbetween every single attempt
- Paths are linked correctly

**More info**
I am using MUSE to compile the website, if there happen to be any known issues with icon fonts. An extensive google search provided me with nothing, though.

**Finally...**
In the end, I would be tremendously thankful if you could provide some insight, or offer a way to work around this.

Comment: are they located on same domain ? have you tried using only one custom font format (just to see if it works)? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16752403/946789 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/16284451/946789

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom fontface showing in tutorial site, but not on mine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377683/custom-fontface-showing-in-tutorial-site-but-not-on-mine)